# Ubuntu 20.04 dual screen menu issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, menu

I have a dual monitor setup, the left monitor being an old HP LA2405x, 24", 60hz refresh rate. The right monitor is a viewsonic vx2458-c-mhd, 24", 144hz.

Naturally I want the Viewsonic to be the primary monitor, however both are active and Viewsonic is primary, the app menu scroll does not work. If I enable the HP as primary with both monitors active the menu scroll works fine.

Answer (score -1):

After playing around with the display setting I found the issue was that the HP native resolution is 1920x1200(16:10) and the Viewsonic is 1920x1080(16:9).

Forcing the HP to display in 1920x1080 fixed the problem.